# How do I get the overload definitions from a class with a script?

Tags: .net, powershell

How do I get the overload definitions from a class with a script?

I have tried by command line and it works.

```
Assembly=[appdomain]::currentdomain.GetAssemblies() | Where-Object Location -match 'FileNet.API'
$Class=$Assembly.GetModules().gettypes()
$Constructors=$Class.GetMembers()| where-object {$_.IsConstructor -eq $True}| where-object {$_.IsPublic-eq $True}


foreach ($constructor in $Constructors) {
    $myconstructor=$constructor.DeclaringType.ToString()
        [type]$mytype=$constructor.DeclaringType
        "========================================="
        $myconstructor
        "========================================="
        $Members=($mytype.DeclaredMembers).Name
        foreach ($Member in $Members) {
            $mytype::$Member.OverloadDefinition
    }
}
```

However this works at the command line

```
$mytype::FetchInstance.OverloadDefinitions
static FileNet.Api.Core.IDomain FetchInstance(FileNet.Api.Core.IConnection conn, string name, FileNet.Api.Property.PropertyFilter filter)
```

Comment: What you're trying to do will only work for static methods

Comment: That is ok with me.

Answer (score 1):

The `::` operator only works for public static methods.

If you want all constructor and method definitions for a type, consider hooking into the `DotNetAdapter` type that generates these overload definitions in the background:

```
function Get-MethodOverload
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [type]$Type
    )

    # Obtain a reference to the DotNetAdapter class
    $NetAdapter = [psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter')
    # Obtain a reference to the GetMethodInfoOverloadDefinition method
    $OverloadResolver = $NetAdapter.GetMethod('GetMethodInfoOverloadDefinition',[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'Static,NonPublic')

    # start with constructors
    foreach($ctor in $Type.GetConstructors())
    {
        $OverloadResolver.Invoke($null,@($ctor.Name,[System.Reflection.MethodBase]$ctor,0))        
    }

    # then methods
    foreach($method in $Type.GetMethods())
    {
        $OverloadResolver.Invoke($null,@($method.Name,[System.Reflection.MethodBase]$method,0))
    }
}
```

Now you can pass your custom class to the function and it'll return the overload definitions:

```
$Assembly = [appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | Where-Object Location -match 'FileNet.API'
$Class = $Assembly.GetTypes() | Where-Object Name -eq 'MyClass'
Get-MethodOverload -Type $Class
```